# Android animation slow inside Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I did several test (click/manual testing) on how `AnimatorSet` `playTogether`, or `ObjectAnimator` performance inside dialog (`DialogFragment` / `AlertDialog`) and compare the speed with `AnimatorSet` in bare inflated layout in activity or fragment. My conclusion of doing animation inside dialog (whether it's a `DialogFragment` or `AlertDialog`) is slow and has glitch in it.

Can anybody confirm it?

To reproduce the issue, firstly create a simple layout file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
         android:id="@+id/view1"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
         android:id="@+id/view2"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

We can replace View (view1, view2) with `CustomView` or `ImageView`, or add some layout constraint for reposition the view. We can replace `ConstraintLayout` also with `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc. Above code is just an illustration purpose.

Inside `Activity` or `DialogFragment`, animate all views using `ObjectAnimator` and `AnimatorSet`:

```kotlin
// find view1 and view2 and declare as variable value

// ....
val listOfView = listOf(view1, view2)
val animSet = AnimatorSet()
val animators = listOfView.map {
    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(it, "rotation", 0f, 360f)
    animator.duration = 1000
    animator.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
    animator.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART                
    animator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    animator
}

animSet.playTogether(animators)
animSet.start()
```

I use kotlin here, because Android now officially support kotlin.

We will observe that animation inside `DialogFragment` has glitch, but animation in Activity / Fragment outperform and fast. Increase the duration to the extreme level such as 500 or 200, and the glitch inside `Dialog` will look more subtle.

Can anybody confirm this issue? And what are the explanation and reason behind that? If there is a way to increase the performance of animation inside dialog, how to achieve that?.